# Issue with network location printing from arg parser in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to give input as network location build but it is printing with extra forward slashes can u please help

python file.py --networklocation \network\path\dest\build_1

But when i am printing it in script it is printing as

\\network\path\dest\build_1/

but expected is \network\path\dest\build_1

```
def __parse_args(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='network location)
    parser.add_argument('--networklocation',required=True, type=str ,help="build location ")
    self._args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

The double backslash which you are getting is not wrong actually.Python print represents it to the user that way only.Try to use opposite looking slashes like,

```
python file.py --networklocation /network/path/dest/build_1
```

But this slash won't be used as an escaping character here

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i want to fetch the files from that build so basically i want to input   \\network\path\dest\build_1 as network string is there any way i can input exclusive rawstring

Comment: try using, path=r'/network/path/dest/build_1'.this will take the path as is.